# How to get first level children for XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to parse a POM file using Nokogiri, and want to get the first level child nodes.

My POM file looks something like this:

```
<project xmlns="some.maven.link">
   <parent>
     <groupId>parent.jar</groupId>
     <artifactId>parent-jar</artifactId>  
   </parent>         
   <groupId>child.jar</groupId>
   <artifactId>child-jar</artifactId>
 </project>
```

I am trying to fetch the artifactId "child-jar" but the XPath that I am using is possibly incorrect and it's fetching me "parent.jar" as the first occurence.

This is my Ruby code:

```
@pom = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(file_path))
p @pom.xpath("/project/artifactId", project"=>"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")[0].text
```

I can access the second element but that just would be a hack.

Comment: Though I don't have the tools to test your ruby code, your XPath should've returned *only* 'child-jar' : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/DI8w0z8D1.

Comment: The problem is the namespace. It's not being referenced in the selector so Nokogiri/libXML2 doesn't know where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML sample does not appear to be correct. Simplifying it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<project>
  <parent>
    <groupId>parent.jar</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-jar</artifactId>  
  </parent>         
  <groupId>child.jar</groupId>
  <artifactId>child-jar</artifactId>
</project>
EOT

doc.at('project > artifactId').text # => "child-jar"
```

Using XPath I'd use:

```
doc.at('/project/artifactId').text # => "child-jar"
```

I'd suggest learning the difference between `search`, `xpath`, `css` and their `at*` cousins which are all documented in the "[Searching a XML/HTML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)" and [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) documentation.

In the above example I removed the XML namespace information to simplify things. XML namespaces are useful, but also are irritating and in your example XML you'd broken it by not supplying a valid URL. Fixing the example with:

```
<project xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I can use:

```
namespaces = doc.collect_namespaces  # => {"xmlns"=>"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
doc.at('project > artifactId', namespaces).text # => "child-jar"
```

or:

```
doc.at('xmlns|project > xmlns|artifactId').text # => "child-jar"
```

I prefer and recommend the first because it's more readable and less noisy.
Nokogiri's implementation of CSS in selectors helps simplify most selectors. Passing in the collected namespaces in the document simplifies searches, whether you're using CSS or XPath.

These also work:

```
doc.at('/xmlns:project/xmlns:artifactId').text # => "child-jar"
doc.at('/foo:project/foo:artifactId', {'foo' => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}).text # => "child-jar"
```

Note that the second uses a renamed namespace, which is useful if you're dealing with redundant `xmlns` declarations in the document and need to differentiate between them.

Nokogiri's "[Namespaces](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces)" tutorial is helpful.